# transposing multiple specific elements onto another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a challenging problem related to 2 large datasets that has had me stumped for awhile now and would love to see some other approaches.

I have two dataframes that I would like to merge without creating duplicated rows. The dataframes consist of tx (treatment) and ae(adverse effects), each with a column named id which correlates data from a particular person .

Data frame for tx:

```
id<-c("A","A","A","B","B")
stage<-c("peak","trough","roll","peak","trough")
start<-c("01-01-2011","01-03-2011","01-05-2011","01-01-2008","01-07-2008")
end<-c("01-02-2011","01-04-2011","01-05-2012","01-05-2008","01-08-2008")
tx<-data.frame(id,stage,start,end)
tx[] <- lapply(tx, as.character)
tx$start<-as.Date(start, format="%d-%m-%Y")
tx$end<-as.Date(end, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

Data frame for ae:

```
id<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
onset<-c("05-01-2011","10-01-2011","14-02-2011","25-01-2011","11-01-2008","11-04-2008","14-07-2008","22-07-2008")
ae<-data.frame(id,onset)
ae[]<-lapply(ae, as.character)
ae$onset<-as.Date(onset, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

So far I have tried `merge(tx,ae)` which does the job but I get duplicates and they are not aligned correctly.

What I need is multiple `ae$onset` dates for a specific person between the dates `tx$start <= ae$onset <= tx$end` to appear in a new column as `ae1, ae2....etc` in the `tx` data frame.

Ultimately I need a transpose function for specific elements that match the specified selection criteria.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have not been able to locate an example of this.

Comment: omgpleasepressthespacebarmoreoften

Comment: @RichScriven space bar or break lines?

Comment: My apologies I thought it would make it more compact by omitting spaces, plus it compensates for my potentially redundant coding lines in my example...

Comment: I thought that this may be a viable solution however my tr column are all 0 which is not helpful..   for(i in 1:length(tx$id)){tx$tr <- length(which(tx$id[i]==ae$id & ae$onset>tx$start[i] & ae$onset<=tx$end[i]))}